# Why do postgres foreign keys have to be the last column in the table?

Tags: postgresql, create-table

This works:

```
CREATE TABLE scans 
(
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ts TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    started TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    finished TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    target_id INTEGER NOT NULL  
        REFERENCES targets ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

but this:

```
CREATE TABLE scans 
(
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ts TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    started TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    target_id INTEGER NOT NULL 
        REFERENCES targets ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    finished TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
);
```

fails with the error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TIMESTAMP"
> LINE 6: SET finished TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE

If I change the lines around further, the error is always at the column-type on the line below the foreign key. Making the foreign key the last column works around the issue.

Why is this?

Comment: Your first example does not work, there is no ',' after `finished TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.  The error you show is for some code you are not showing, note the `SET`.  Please edit your question to fix. FYI, a FK does not have to be the last field.

Comment: [Works for me...](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=c2e2da35aac0d870dddb5de20087ab0e)

Comment: Must be something else, that syntax does work: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ca19cf191f25c3cfe57da6b96e26083e

Comment: it works in both cases for me but you have to add ','  after 'ZONE' in first example.

Comment: But ironically the one you claim does work doesn't, since there's one comma missing after `finished ...` and one to much after `target_id ...`. Please be sure to test the statements before you post them and that they actually work/induce the error as claimed.

Comment: Oh and why is there a `SET` before `finished` in the error message? That's nowhere an either of the statements.

Comment: @stickybit Sorry, cut and paste error - now fixed.

Comment: Nope. Still a comma to much in the second one. The first one is still working. And there still is that `SET` in the error message that indicates the message isn't related to any of the statements. Again: Make sure to test the statements before you post them and that they actually work/induce the error as claimed!

Comment: Completely offtopic: When there is a start timestamp and an end timestamp, I would start thinking about a timestamp range. tstzrange in your case. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for looking at this.

The issue is that copying the SQL from an open file in Microsoft Code and pasting it into psql results in the word "SET" being added.

```
CREATE TABLE scans (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ts TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    started TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    target_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES nmap_targets ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    finished TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
);
```

when pasted becomes:

```
spider=# CREATE TABLE scans (
spider(# id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
spider(# ts TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
spider(# started TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
spider(# target_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES nmap_targets ON UPDATE CASCADE,
spider(# SET finished TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
spider(# );
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TIMESTAMP"
LINE 6: SET finished TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
                     ^
```

It's interpreting the tabs as autocompletes.

Normally there is nothing to autocomplete, but when it's just seen "... UPDATE CASCADE," it thinks that "SET" is what comes next.

Comment: I had that problem too, and it was hard to figure out.